# How to right click and save the image?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to right click and save the image on selenium java. right click is working but unable to save the image.

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(Image).build().perform();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
action.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,"V").build().perform();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can get the URI of the image and download that directly rather than right clicking.

Comment: the webdriver is pretty much constrained to the DOM.  Interacting with the browser won't work.  An alternative would be to get the src attribute, and download that directly in your native code.  (Java has URL to file method...)